# What is "workspace polling" in the context of Jenkins?

Tags: git, jenkins, build, jenkins-plugins, workspace

In Jenkins, under **Source Code Management**,
There is an area to add **Additional Behaviors**.

One of those options is:
**"Force polling using workspace"**

What does that mean?  When would I decide to use it?
How does it correlate to `git`?

I assume it has something to do with pulling down changes on branches,
but if we do a fresh clone, each time, would this option matter?

Answer (score 5):

The [Git Jenkins plugin doc includes](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin):

> ### Fast Remote Polling
>
> Fast Remote Polling is a feature that uses a speedy 'git ls-remote ...' command to perform the SCM polling action rather than having to a clone and fetch a local repository.
>
> This feature is enabled by default as of versions 2.2+.
>
> In the event that Fast Remote Polling is detected as being not possible (branches to build contains wildcards, etc), polling will fallback to requiring a workspace.
>
> However, it is possible in some environments that Fast Remote Polling will not work due to the fact that it executes on the master and the master may not have a working Git installation.
>
> **A workaround for this is to add an additional behavior of Force polling using workspace to all jobs where you want to use SCM polling.**

That means detecting changes by polling (git pull/git checkout) in a workspace vs. querying the remote repo with `git ls-remote`.
That was discussed in [`JENKINS-10131`](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-10131).